# "RdlCompile" task was not found

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reporting, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I'm trying to compile and project with rldc file, and i'm getting one of two errors, either:

> The "Microsoft.Reporting.RdlCompile" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

or:

> The "RdlCompile" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.

I'm using VS2010, and I've re-installed Reporting Viewer, made sure the target files and the task definition are correct, and even tried to copy the dll from another computer, and nothing worked.

Did anyone encounter this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by copying the content of the folder:

> [Program Files]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\

and the task declaration in the file:

> [Program Files] \MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets

from another computer.

For some reason re-installing doesn't work, but copying from a working machine does.